# How do I get the product per row using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the product per row in the table?

```
Example in table:

data1 data2 data3  total
1      2      3     6
2      2      3     12
```

Here is my html table that I have created:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function() {
      // get the values from this row:
      var $data1 = $('.data1', this).val();
      var $data2 = $('.data2', this).val();
      var $data3 = $('.data3', this).val();
      var $total = ($data3 * 1) * ($data2 * 1) * ($data3 * 1);
      $('.multTotal', this).val($total);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      data1
    </th>
    <th>
      data2
    </th>
    <th>
      data3
    </th>
    <th>
      total
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="txtMult">
    <td>
      <input name="data1" class="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data2" class="data2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data3" class="data3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="multTotal" type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: when I run your code it works ok. is there anything unexpected from that?

Comment: @guradio I have appended another row using a jquery, however the second and the next row that auto computes the total aren't evaluated. The original row is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help.

I got the solution for these

```
`$(document).on("keyup", ".data1, .data2, .data3", function() {
    var tablerow = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");

    var data1 = tablerow.find(".data1").val();
    var data2 = tablerow.find(".data2").val();
    var data3 = tablerow.find(".data3").val();

    var total = data1 * data2 * data3;
    tablerow.find(".multTotal").val(total);
});
`
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this and its multiplying correctly. You had it doing data3 * data2 * data3 instead of 1 2 and 3

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function() {
      // get the values from this row:
      var $data1 = $('.data1', this).val();
      var $data2 = $('.data2', this).val();
      var $data3 = $('.data3', this).val();
      var $total = ($data1) * ($data2) * ($data3);
      $('.multTotal', this).val($total);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      data1
    </th>
    <th>
      data2
    </th>
    <th>
      data3
    </th>
    <th>
      total
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="txtMult">
    <td>
      <input name="data1" class="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data2" class="data2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data3" class="data3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="multTotal" type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $data1 = $( ".data1" ).val();
var $data2 = $( ".data2" ).val();
var $data3 = $( ".data3" ).val();
var $total = ($data1) * ($data2) * ($data3);
$('.multTotal').val($total);
```

put the val in each var then multiplied, then put the total in the multiTotal :)

Comment: Is my function correctly constructed? because I cannot alert the data1 or any value from these 3 datas.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Thanks @Static Void

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function() {
      // get the values from this row:
      var $data1 = $('.data1', this).val();
      var $data2 = $('.data2', this).val();
      var $data3 = $('.data3', this).val();
      var $total = ($data1 * 1) * ($data2 * 1) * ($data3 * 1);
      $('.multTotal', this).val($total);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      data1
    </th>
    <th>
      data2
    </th>
    <th>
      data3
    </th>
    <th>
      total
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="txtMult">
    <td>
      <input name="data1" class="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data2" class="data2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data3" class="data3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="multTotal" type="number" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In case I add a new set of rows of data1, data2, data3. Is it Ok having same class names and evaluates each of the specific total row?

Comment: Thanks @Hong Vat Vit